# R: Fixed widths aligned left

Tags: r, fixed-width

I am trying to save a `data.frame` to a file in this way:

```
library(gdata)
write.fwf(mydata,file = "myfile.txt",width = c(12, 7), eol="\r\n", colnames = FALSE, justify = "left")
```

the data are very plain:

```
V1 V2
1   foo
2   bar
3   ter
4   four
```

However the generated output put the values aligned to right instead of left:

```
           1    foo
           2    bar
etc
```

instead of

```
1            foo
2            bar
etc
```

so it pads from the left with spaces instead from the right.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the help page of `write.fwf` and `format` indicate: the `justify` argument only applies to character columns. It doesn't seem possible to left align number using `format`.

One way to do this would be to first cast the numeric column to a character column manually using, for example, `sprintf`:

```
mydata$V1 <- sprintf("%-12d", mydata$V1)
```

The `%d` indicates that you want to format an integer, the 12 is the width of the field and the `-` indicates left alignment.

I must say, that this is what I usually do when writing fixed width files: first convert all column to character with the correct widths etc, and then do:

```
lines <- do.call(paste0, mydata)
writeLines(lines, "myfile.txt")
```

Comment: Well not really confy :) especially with many columns but it is ok as long as you can convert the columns with `as.character` or skipping `stringAsFactors` etc